# Is there a difference between inequality and equality sign when using Lagrange multiplier?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, lagrange-multiplier

For example,

find the extreme values of z=xy subject to the condition x+y=1

This is quite simple example of finding extreme using Lagrange multiplier

When the constrain is changed from x+y=1 to x+y<1 (or less than or equal to ).

Is there a difference when using Lagrange multiplier, or is it just same as equality sign?

Just let inequality be equality and do as in usual way and find every point satisfying

inequality sign?

Comment: Did they already speak about slack variables ?

Comment: What is slack variable.?

Comment: So, your answer is : no ! OK, one of the ways to adress inequality is to rewrite, say, $x+y<1$ as $x+y=1+s$ , $s$ being the slack variable. Don't worry : you will hear about it. But, just as you suspected, the problem is not the same.